# perl unary ~ gives not the expected result

Tags: php, perl, bit, unary-operator

I'm trying to port a php algorithm to perl but I struggle with one bit operator I'm not familiar with...

so the php code looks like this:

```
...
$var = '348492634';
print ~$var;
...
```

result: -348492635

doing the exact same thing in perl:

```
...
$var = '348492634';
print ~$var;
...
```

result: 18446744073361058981

I read a lot about the integer size depending on the architecture of the cpu, but I never found a working solution. Maybe I'm just using the wrong function in perl...

It's necessary for the logic to get same result as in the php script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unary `~` coerces input to an integer, not a hex string as your code comment suggests.

Comment: @mob `~` works on strings too: `"\xCE\xCD\xCC" eq ~"123"`. EggL's output isn't produced by the code he is showing, there is another numification somewhere.

Comment: @amon It might depend on the PHP version. It's amusing to look at the comments on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php and watch everybody try to reimplement the `~` operator.

Comment: @mob sorry, I was talking about the Perl snippet, and mistook your comment for talking about Perl too. Of course, Php's `~` is int32-only. (Oh dear, the [reimplementation looking at each char](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php#112699) in a stringification hurt … although I wrote similar code earlier today).

Answer (score 2):

Seems that on your setup, PHP ints are 32bit signed while perl ints are 64bit unsigned.

This will probably do what you need on the given system but it is not guaranteed to work the same if you use it on another installation of perl.

```
$var = '348492634'; #hex!
print ~($var - 2**32) - 2**32;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do for both `$var='348492634'` (which you claim to have) and `$var=348492634` (which you did have):

```
unpack('l', ~pack('l', $var))
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty conversion is:

```
print -($var+1);    # like ~$var in PHP
```

If your perl is using 64-bit integers, this will only fail for `$var=-18446744073709551616`
(`0x8000000000000000`), which is a value you wouldn't use in 32-bit PHP anyway.